# Can I perform a local test for DNS leaking?

Tags: vpn, dns, automated-testing

I want to test that the connection from my local machine to my VPN is set up correctly, specifically that I do not have DNS leaks.

I am aware of [web-based tools like dnsleaktest.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129917/7062) but they aren't suitable for repeated and/or scripted testing.

Is it possible to perform a local test for DNS leaks?

Comment: worth looking at https://github.com/emanuele-f/DNSleak

Comment: why not packet captures?

Comment: that other question you linked mentions the actual JS code used *client-side*: https://github.com/piwik/piwik/blob/master/js/piwik.js

Answer (score 1):

[DNSleak](https://github.com/emanuele-f/DNSleak) inspects DNS packets on the local network interface to detect
leaks. Unlike web-based solutions, it works at the local computer
level. No third party servers are used and DNS leak result is a true /
false response. [See the README for more details.](https://github.com/emanuele-f/DNSleak/blob/master/README.md)

Installation instructions for Debian-based systems (usage instructions in README):

```
# download code
git clone https://github.com/emanuele-f/DNSleak.git

# install prerequisites
sudo apt install libpcap0.8-dev libndpi-dev pkg-config

# install from source
cd dnsleak
make
sudo make install PREFIX=/usr install

# basic usage
sudo dnsleak <interface>
```